# how to find pressure of a liquid when given volume (1 and 2) and one pressure?

Tags: vapor-pressure

A 5 mL sample of an unknown liquid is placed into a 250 mL flask that has had all of the air removed.  The pressure measured in the flask is found to be 35.4kPa.  In a seperate trial the student puts 214 mL of the same liquid into the same flask at the same conditions.  What will the pressure measure (in kPa) in the second trial?

I've looked through my notes and I don't have a formula or anything in there that I can use volume with. Can someone help me start this question?

Comment: Maybe the liquid volume doesn't matter.  Maybe you don't need an equation.  Remember that in an (ideal) gas, pressure and concentration at a given temperature are really just two ways of talking about the same thing.  I hope I didn't just confuse you more, but I think you are making it too hard.

Comment: i didnt think of it that way. im definatly overthinking! thanks for your help!